# Key event detection failed in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jsf, primefaces

I am tracking the keyboard events for p:intputText in Primefaces/JSF which updates another components. 
My code is :

```
    <p:remoteCommand name="test" actionListener="#{cpeTrainingEntryMB.setTrainingDetails}" 
    update=":mainForm:trainingCert :mainForm:selectDays :mainForm:trainingSchedule :mainForm:presentDays :mainForm:creditHr :messageGrowl" />
   <p:inputText id="trainingNo" value="#{cpeTrainingEntryMB.cpeMemEntry.trainingNo.trainingNo}" 
   onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 9) { test(),traingFocus(); return false; }" >
    </p:inputText>
```

I have tracked "event.keyCode == 9", and works well in Firefox but this key event does not work in Google Chrome as well as IE.

I have tried Google but cannot find appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1. `onkeypress` check on <kbd>Tab</kbd> isn't crossbrowser compatible. Use `onkeydown` instead.
2. The comma is an invalid line statement separator. You need semicolon.

So, all in all, this should do:

```
<p:inputText ... onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 9) { test(); trainingFocus(); }" />
```

---

That said, it's that the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key code value of `9` is luckily the same across all browsers, but normally you'd like to use jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead. It'll give you a cross browser compatible `event` back. PrimeFaces ships as being a jQuery based JSF component library already with jQuery out the box. You should be able to use it directly without any additional scripts.

E.g.

```
<p:inputText ... styleClass="trainingFocuser" />
```

With this (in a real JS file!)

```
$(document).on("keydown", ".trainingFocuser", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        test();
        trainingFocus();
    }
});
```

#### See also:

- [JavaScript Event KeyCode Test Page](http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html)
- [QuirksMode.org - keydown, keypress, keyup](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply and for 'semicolon'. But I need to do on 'Tab', so 'onblur' event is not my choice. And could u please demonstrate about '.on()' in Primefaces/JSF.

Comment: Thanks.. I am ok with 'onkeypress'